# How to create a help overlay,iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, overlay

I am trying to do a help overlay like in this image below, how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: What's your code? A UIView with background color to black and low opacity/alpha?

Comment: You can use view with background colour balck and alfa 5.

Answer (score 1):

do like

**Objective-C**

```
// get window screen size for frame
CGRect screensize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//create a new UIview with the same size for same view
UIView* TransprentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screensize];

// change the background color to black and the opacity to 0.6 for Transparent
TransprentView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];

  // here add your Label, Image, etc, what ever you want

// add this TransprentView to your main view
[self.view addSubview:TransprentView];
```

you can romove it from superview:

```
[TransprentView removeFromSuperview];
```

**Swift 2 & above**

```
 let TransprentView =  UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    TransprentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    // here add your Label, Image, etc, what ever you want

    self.view.addSubview(TransprentView)
```

you can romove it from superview:

```
    TransprentView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: would u need assistance for this work ask me,

Answer (score 0):

You can make one overlay image for each iPhone size in Photoshop with a alpha of 50 then just add that image into a `UIImageView` with a `CGRect` of `self.view.frame` and control the hiding and unhiding with a `UIGestureRecognizer` on the image touch.

Or you can simply make a `UIView` with a background color of `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f]` then add each individual "hand" images where you want them inside this view.